# Magento 2.3.4 Advanced JS Bundling: Should a `deps` node entry within a `shim` node be copied into `deps` module in the build.js file?

Tags: magento2.3, frontend, advanced-bundling

My store's requirejs-config.js has an entry for `shim` node as seen in the code snippet below, that includes an entry for `deps` node as well. I wonder if I should copy this `deps` node entry to the corresponding `deps` node although it is originally a part of `shim` node.

```
(function() {
var config = {
    shim: {
        'Swissup_Pagespeed/js/lib/loadCSS': {
            exports: 'loadCSS'
        },
        'Swissup_Pagespeed/js/lib/cssrelpreload': {
            deps: [
                'Swissup_Pagespeed/js/lib/loadCSS'
            ]
        }
    },
    deps: [
        'jquery/jquery.cookie'
    ]
};

require.config(config);
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything that is found within a particular configuration shouldn't be copied into another node whose name resembles with the entries within another as my example shows.